# ModuleNotFoundError only on system but not on Colab

Tags: python-3.x, module, google-colaboratory

The following error is not occurring when I run my code on Colab. And I am facing this error when I try to run on my system

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 224, in <module>
    import infun
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'infun'
```

I changed to the directory in which my `infun` present i.e., `infunner` at the start of my program `program.py`

```
import os
os.chdir('infunner')
```

And I find no difference in paths of files provided for program execution in both Colab and on my system.

What is the reason for this error?

---

The file structure is as follows

```
├───program.py
├───infunner
│   ├───infun
│   ...
...
```